# No components visible in visual editor of Vaadin

Tags: java, eclipse, vaadin, visual-editor

Do you know why I can't see the components in the visual editor of Vaadin. The thing is that if I drag'n'drop from there, I can put the components into the layout. They are just not visible.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

because its about `jre`,

**solution**

you should install `7u71` to see your components visible in visual editor of Vaadin